# Stuck trying to get Game Center Leaderboard to work

Tags: ios, lua, coronasdk, game-center, google-play-games

I am trying to get a gamecenter leaderboard to work, but have gotten stuck. I am testing on the Xcode simulator because I was having trouble logging in to our sandbox account on a device. I am able to login to the sandbox account through the game using the init function, but the leaderboard does not show up in gamecenter. Under games it shows our game but underneath it says "No leaderboards or achievements". I have set up a leaderboad in itunes connect, and have requests to setHighScore in the code that seem to be working. Here is the relevant code:

```
local function updateCallback(e)
    local data = json.encode( e.data )

    -- show encoded json string via native alert
    native.showAlert( "e.data", data, { "OK" } )
end

--[[
    Update the gamecenter learderboard for gamescore.
]]--
function [app name]GameNetwork.updateGamescore()
    --Sets the score if it is higher than the one on Apple's server
    gameNetwork.request( "setHighScore",
    {
        localPlayerScore = { category = "com.[domain].[game].gamescore", value = gamescore },
        listener = updateCallback
    })
end
```

As expected the update callback displays

```
{"value": 25,"category":"com.[domain].[game].gamescore"}
```

when the `updateGamescore` function is called. Am I missing something? Any good tutorials on the gamenetwork api?

[Cross-post from corona forum](http://forums.coronalabs.com/topic/44940-stuck-trying-to-get-game-center-leaderboard-to-work/)

Comment: I have the same problem for Google Play Game Services testing on a device. The "setHighScore" request seems to be sent successfully, but the leaderboard does not show up in Gamecenter or Google Play games. I feel like I missed a step somewhere, but not sure what it is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally figured it out.  The issue was with the app id. Our ad hoc provisioning profile had a wild card, while our app store one did not. I created a new adhoc provisioning profile with the specific app id, and the leaderboards showed up immediately. Also our adhoc provisioning profile was using a different certificate than the app store certificate, so that may have been the issue as well.